# Why must I import my delegate header files?

Tags: iphone, delegates

I am always finding that if I create a delegate and then assign a class to conform to it I have to explicitly import the delegate .h file into that class otherwise I get an error stating the protocol cannot be found?

Am I missing a global setting somewhere that allows my project to find my delegate?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is normal and expected. Otherwise that compiler would ALWAYS have to parse all headers prior to being able to compile code possibly totally unrelated to most header files.

Comment: I understand this, but I am always seeing examples where no import takes place and it does not appear in the .pch file?  This is why I am confused how some folks code does not seem to perform and import and there is no error???

Comment: You must be talking about iOS SDK protocols - specifically about UIKit and not custom protocols defined by your own code then?
For those cases, take a peek at the UIKit/UIKit.h header and learn :D ... they simply include all relevant headers.

Comment: No, Im talking about sample code from books I purchase AKA:   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PRPSplashScreen.h"

@interface AppDelegate_iPhone : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, PRPSplashScreenDelegate> {}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet PRPSplashScreen *splashScreen;

@end
But WAIT!  OMG what a plonker I am!  I just realised the delegate in imported in the header file "PRPSplashScreen.h"    DOH!!!  Sorry for posting a stupid question :-((((

Comment: although in my defence...the book does not state as such...  I had to rummage through the sample code to see it!

Answer (score 1):

You can add it into your MyApp_Prefix.pch file if you want it to be added to every class's header. This obviously has some build performance issues, but other than that, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: +1 for good workaround -- even though I personally do not like such solution as it makes the entire dependency logic harder to understand for third party coders looking at your code.

Comment: @Till: Yea, I don't do this either for the reasons you specified, but thought i'd offer it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is standard C stuff. You need to import your source file before using it. The delegate file is just another header file.